# No way was I going vs No way I was going

Tags: word-order, inversion, subject-auxiliary-inversion

Can you explain to me why there is so order of words in the sentence (from my book):

> I'd been asking Mom for a year to let me go back to Ridgefield, our hometown in Illinois, and see my friends. **No way was I going** to let Ashley go back before me, so I was glad when Mom told her no, that she would miss too much school.

I think text in bold should be "No way I was going". Why reason to write in such order?

Comment: In AmE, no way is short for the expression: There is no way, there was no way. That said, English also uses **inversions** with the be verb at times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some Unnatural Word Order Concerning Subject-Verb Inversion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/303588/some-unnatural-word-order-concerning-subject-verb-inversion)

Comment: Yes, I've looked up verb-inversion in google and found explanation and usage of that.

Comment: @ZWA Did it answer your question, or are you still unsure of the reason for the word order here?